# Python. How to call a function from a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to have a dictionary where a certain key calls a value... that value is a function and I would want that function to execute.
Below is my attempt to do it but all I get is the value of where it is stored in memory.

```
class Testing:
    def __init__(self):
        self.method = {'Method1': self.another, 'Method2': self.there}

    def launch(self, input):
        print(self.method[input])

    @staticmethod
    def another():
        print('This print statement should pop out.')

    @staticmethod
    def there():
        print('This should not appear.')

new = Testing()
new.launch('Method1')
```

The result that I get from that is:

```
<function Testing.another at 0x01519540>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `def launch(self, input): self.method[input]()` is enough.

Comment: just add a bracket at the end, same as you do with any function when you want to call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the actual function call: (notice the added `()` at the end)

```
def launch(self, input):
        print(self.method[input]())
```